# Logo and menu in same alignment in html

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner in HTML and CSS. I want to put a logo and and a menu in the same alignment. I put the logo and menu in same div and tried to float them on left and right respectively, but still the logo and the menu are in different alignments.

Here is my code: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t8LDg/3/)

the HTML part:

```
<div class="set header">
    <div class name="set logo">
        <img src="image/r3v_logo2.png" alt=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="set mainmenu">
        <ul> 
            <li><a href="">Home</a> </li> 
            <li><a href="">Forum</a> </li>
            <li><a href="">Gallery</a> </li> 
            <li><a href="">About Us</a> </li> 
            <li><a href="">Facebook</a> </li>
            <li><a href="">Help & FAQ</a> </li> 
        </ul>
    </div>                      
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: `<div class name="set logo">` remove name from here.

Comment: so kind of you, but it didn't work either.

Comment: add `display: inline-block` on the div with te class "logo" so it behaves like a inline block in the menu row

Comment: thanks man! you rock!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from this:

```
<div class name="logo">
```

to this:

```
<div class="logo">
```

then on css, try to follow this code:

```
.logo {
float:right; (it depends on you if you want to place it on left or right)
}

.mainmenu {
float:right;
}
```

Here's your code that I'd try to test:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="image/r3v_logo2.png" alt=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="mainmenu">
        <ul> 
            <li><a href="">Home</a> </li> 
            <li><a href="">Forum</a> </li>
            <li><a href="">Gallery</a> </li> 
            <li><a href="">About Us</a> </li> 
            <li><a href="">Facebook</a> </li>
            <li><a href="">Help & FAQ</a> </li> 
        </ul>
    </div>                      
 </div>
```

or

```
 <div class="header">
    <div class="logo" style="float:right">
        <img src="image/r3v_logo2.png" alt=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="mainmenu" style="float:right">
        <ul> 
            <li><a href="">Home</a> </li> 
            <li><a href="">Forum</a> </li>
            <li><a href="">Gallery</a> </li> 
            <li><a href="">About Us</a> </li> 
            <li><a href="">Facebook</a> </li>
            <li><a href="">Help & FAQ</a> </li> 
        </ul>
    </div>                      
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div class="set header">
    <div class name="set logo" style="float:left;">
        <img src="image/r3v_logo2.png" alt=""/>
     </div>

    <div class="set mainmenu" style="float:left;">
       <ul> 
           <li><a href="">Home</a> </li> 
           <li><a href="">Forum</a> </li>
           <li><a href="">Gallery</a> </li> 
           <li><a href="">About Us</a> </li> 
           <li><a href="">Facebook</a> </li>
           <li><a href="">Help & FAQ</a> </li> 
       </ul>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this fiddle

[Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/t8LDg/3/)

```
       <div class="set main">
            <div class="set header">
                <div class name="set logo">
                    <img src="image/r3v_logo2.png" alt=""/>
                    <div class="set mainmenu">
                    <ul> 
                        <li><a href="">Home</a> </li> 
                        <li><a href="">Forum</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="">Gallery</a> </li> 
                        <li><a href="">About Us</a> </li> 
                        <li><a href="">Facebook</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="">Help & FAQ</a> </li> 
                    </ul>
                </div>  
                </div>

            </div>
</div>
```

> Div is display block

so it will occupy whole row instead if you want to align two value in horizontal you can put them in a same div

Answer (score 0):

**Now replace this**

```
<div class name="set logo"> // not define your class
```

**Into this**

```
<div class="set logo"> // here define your class
```

Answer (score 0):

See updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/t8LDg/6/

The div that wraps the logo has to have `display: inline-block` and remove the `float: right` from the menu

```
    <div class="set main">
        <div class="set header">
            <div class name="set logo" style="display: inline-block;">
                <img src="http://3rxg9qea18zhtl6s2u8jammft.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/lufthansa.jpg" width="200" alt=""/>
            </div>
            <div class="set mainmenu">
                <ul> 
                    <li><a href="">Home</a> </li> 
                    <li><a href="">Forum</a> </li>
                    <li><a href="">Gallery</a> </li> 
                    <li><a href="">About Us</a> </li> 
                    <li><a href="">Facebook</a> </li>
                    <li><a href="">Help & FAQ</a> </li> 
                </ul>
            </div>                      
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all change

> ```
> <div class name="set logo">
> ```

to this

> ```
> <div class="set logo">
> ```

as mentioned by Rohit Azad.

When you make the above change the logo and the menu will be aligned.

The other way is

```
.logo{ 
    float: left; // Remove this line
}
.mainmenu{ 
    float:right; // Remove this line
}
```

Since there is already a `display:inline-block;` for the above you don't need to float the logo and menu.

Answer (score 0):

**Change HTML as follows**

```
        <div class="set main">
        <div class="set header">
            <div class="set logo">
                <img src="image/r3v_logo2.png" alt=""/>
            </div>
            <div class="set mainmenu">
                <ul> 
                    <li><a href="">Home</a> </li> 
                    <li><a href="">Forum</a> </li>
                    <li><a href="">Gallery</a> </li> 
                    <li><a href="">About Us</a> </li> 
                    <li><a href="">Facebook</a> </li>
                    <li><a href="">Help & FAQ</a> </li> 
                </ul>
            </div>                      
        </div>
      </div>
```

**Change CSS as follows**

```
* {
   margin:0; 
   padding:0;
  }
body {
  font-family:calibri;
  font-size:14px;
  color:#666;
 }
.set{   overflow:hidden  }
.main{  width:960px; margin: 30px auto; display: block;}
.logo{   width: 200px;
        display: inline-block;
        float: left; 
        padding:0px;
        }
.logo img {width: 100%;}
.mainmenu{ width: 710px;
   display: inline-block;float:right;background:black}
.mainmenu ul{margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none;}
.mainmenu ul li{float:left;border-right: 1px hidden #FFFFFF}
.mainmenu ul li a{display:block;color:white; font-size: 18px;
 padding:20px 25px;text- decoration:none}
.mainmenu ul li a:hover{color:red}
```

Please use following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t8LDg/7/) url

Answer (score 0):

From this:

```
<div class name="set logo">
  <img src="image/r3v_logo2.png" alt=""/>
</div>
```

To this:

```
<div class="set logo">
  <img src="image/r3v_logo2.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

And remove the padding from the .logo selector:

```
.logo {
    width: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/seemly/t8LDg/9/